# How can I keep track of equivalent functions in different programming languages?

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a source-to-source compiler that is intended to translate programs between different programming languages. Right now, I'm trying to find a way to keep track of equivalent functions in different programming languages, so that I can find out which function in one language is equivalent to the same function in another language.

Given an array like the one, is it possible to write a function that will return the corresponding function in another language (e. g., using a query such as `print(getCorrespondingValue("Python", [["Java", "System.out.println"]]))`, which would return the function in Python that corresponds to `System.out.println` in Java)?

```
correspondingFunctionDatabase = [
    [
        ["Java", "System.out.println"], ["JavaScript", "console.log"], ["Python", "print"],
    ],
    [
        ["Java", "s1.replaceAll(str1, str2);"], ["JavaScript", "str.replace(str1, str2)"], ["Python", "str.replace(str1, str2)"], ["Haxe", "replace(str, str1, str2)"]
    ],
    [
        ["JavaScript", "str.split(separator)"], ["Java", "str.split(separator)"], ["Python", "re.split(separator, string)"]
    ],
    [
        ["JavaScript", "eval(statement)"], ["Python", "eval(statement)"] 
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it's not going to be fast if you stick to lists. This is the kind of problem that relational databases are good at.

Comment: Questions that ask for code usually require prior solution attempts, but [self-answered questions such as this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186983/how-to-correctly-post-a-qa-style-question-i-e-self-answer-without-it-failing) appear to be an exception to this rule.

Comment: To be perfectly honest. I find this extremely underwhelming for a self-answered question. This doesn't expose anything new, nor does it have much practical use. Is it possible to print items from a list? Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: @larsmans The function `getCorrespondingValue` (which I implemented in my answer below) acts similar to a database query: it accepts a list of key-value pairs, along with the key that corresponds to the output, and then returns the value that corresponds to the input. It's not a relational database, but it still works.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus This question isn't asking how to print items from a list: it's asking how to obtain a function in one language that corresponds to functions in various other languages, based on the matching key-value pair(s) that are given as input. This is a fairly complex problem, and solving it required a significant amount of effort on my part.

Comment: You're printing items from a list dude. It would be a lot easier if you used a dictionary, but you just have a list of lists. I don't mean to be disparaging, but you've even got unused operators and a lot of fluff code that isn't doing anything for you.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus In that case, how could I use a dictionary to accomplish the same task? I'm not sure how it would simplify the problem further: do you know of a better solution than the one that I've found?

Comment: I mentioned the dictionary because you mentioned that you had key-value pairs, which you don't quite have. You've got lists of length two which have no concept of keys. I'll post  solution shortly.

Comment: I don't want to say I told you so... but I totally told you so dude.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Matching equivalent functions might be *why* you're doing it; but what you're doing is storing pairs of strings

Comment: I feel people are being a little harsh here - we all start somewhere and I don't think there was any malice here. The asker has learned from this, and that's great - I understand the knee-jerk reaction to some underwhelming code, but let's try and be a little more supportive.

Comment: @Lattyware I really don't expect anyone to be supportive here. Everyone is trying to tell me that I'm a sub-standard Python programmer, and they're probably right: someone even [claimed that one of my working solutions was the "worst Python code they had read all week."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17665044/975097) Should I just give on programming in general, since everyone here is trying to convice me that I'm worthless?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Don't get over the top about it - people can be supportive on here, the self-answered question seems to have pushed people to be on the offence about the quality of this code, but don't take it hard - everyone starts somewhere. Keep learning if you want to. The community over-reacted a bit here, but it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Build a lookup first, then access that:

```
from itertools import permutations
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(dict)
for row in correspondingFunctionDatabase:
    for fst, snd in permutations(row, 2):
        dd[tuple(fst)][snd[0]] = snd[1]

print dd['Java', 'System.out.println']['Python']
# print
print dd['JavaScript', 'eval(statement)']['Python']
# eval(statement)
print dd['JavaScript', 'eval(statement)'].get('FakeLanguage', 'No Matching Function')
# No Matching Function
```

As a note, this also means you can get what languages a statement can be translated to, eg:

```
print list(dd["Java", "s1.replaceAll(str1, str2);"])
# ['Python', 'Haxe', 'JavaScript']
```

Comment: This is quite impressive. It's much better than my own solution - no wonder my question got so many downvotes. I didn't realize how uninformed I really was until now. (Perhaps I'll never be forgiven for appearing to be so ignorant, but at least I can learn something from all of the people who are less ignorant than I am).

Comment: @AndersonGreen just been going through my old answers in case I need to update anything - it's good to see you're still active and that this question hasn't discouraged your participation on SO

Answer (score 5):

As per requested in the comments, this is probably how I would generally implement this. In actuality I'd use a Mongo Database, but leaving that out from brevity.

```
DB = [
{"Java": "System.out.println", "JavaScript": "console.log", "Python", "print"},
{"Java": "s1.replaceAll(str1, str2);", "JavaScript": "str.replace(str1, str2)", "Python": "str.replace(str1, str2)", "Haxe": "replace(str, str1, str2)"},
{"JavaScript": "str.split(separator)", "Java": "str.split(separator)", "Python": "re.split(separator, string)"}
{"JavaScript": "eval(statement)", "Python": "eval(statement)"}]

def get_corresponding_value(language, entry):
    try:
        index = [value for key,value in DB if key == entry[0]].index(entry[1])
        return DB[index].get(language, "No equivalent found")
    except ValueError:
        print "Could not find function: %s " % entry[1]
        raise
```

Or the one-liner for the fetishists:

```
get_equiv = lambda language,entry: DB[[value for key,value in DB if key==entry[0]].index(entry[1])][language]
```

I know the try except is a little excessive, but unhandled errors are a pet peeve of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a way simpler solution to this:

```
# Build a list of dicts. Each dict maps language names
# to function names.
cfDicts = [dict(x) for x in correspondingFunctionDatabase]

def getCorrespondingValue(lang, construct):
    # Select all dicts that have an entry for lang and for
    # the given construct. A construct is a tuple of the
    # form (language, function).
    ds = [d for d in cfDicts if lang in d and
                                construct[0] in d and
                                d[construct[0]] == construct[1]]
    if len(ds) == 0:
        # There is no equivalent for `lang` to `construct`.
        return None
    else:
        # There should be only one match.
        assert len(ds) == 1, 'Multiple entries for' + str(construct)
        # Return the first match.
        return ds[0][lang]
```

Note that I've change the second argument to contain only one construct. It's easy (and pointless) to modify it to accepts multiple constructs.

Examples:

```
In [117]: getCorrespondingValue("Python", ["Java", "System.out.println"])
print
```

Comment: There is in fact a simpler solution. Simple than this even.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus, agreed, seems like you, Jon, and I submitted simultaneously. Your and my solution seem to be pretty much the same.

Comment: heh, funny how that works out. I really like Jon's solution. I added a one-liner for flair though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, using two dicts:

```
equivalenceclasses = {n: dict(map(tuple,klass)) for n,klass in enumerate(correspondingFunctionDatabase)}
bypair = {tuple(pair):n for n,klass in enumerate(correspondingFunctionDatabase) for pair in klass}

#note pep8 style name
def get_corresponding_function(targetlang, pair):
    # you could catch exceptions here
    return equivalenceclasses.get(bypair.get(tuple(pair))).get(targetlang)

print get_corresponding_function("Python", ["Java", "System.out.println"])
```

Each row in your "database" represents a class; each such class can be identified by an integer, and that integer can be used to join across the two dicts. Of course, you could just use a `sqlite` (or other sql) or freeform database.

See it in action here: http://ideone.com/oxrdEV

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it's definitely possible to do this. I have written a complete working solution in Python.

First, I created an array of corresponding functions in different programming languages:

```
correspondingFunctionDatabase = [
    [
        ["Java", "System.out.println"], ["JavaScript", "console.log"], ["Python", "print"],
    ],
    [
        ["Java", "s1.replaceAll(str1, str2);"], ["JavaScript", "str.replace(str1, str2)"], ["Python", "str.replace(str1, str2)"], ["Haxe", "replace(str, str1, str2)"]
    ],
    [
        ["JavaScript", "str.split(separator)"], ["Java", "str.split(separator)"], ["Python", "re.split(separator, string)"]
    ],
    [
        ["JavaScript", "eval(statement)"], ["Python", "eval(statement)"] 
    ]
]
```

Next, I wrote a function called `getCorrespondingValue`, which will return the function for one language that corresponds to a function in another language:

```
def containsAll(containingArray, containsAllOfThese):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(containsAllOfThese)):
        if((containsAllOfThese[i] in containingArray) == False):
            return False
        i += 1
    return True

def getCorrespondingValue(valueToRetrieve, valueCorrespondsTo, mainArray=correspondingFunctionDatabase, printMessages=False):
    i = 0
    correspondingValues = []
    while(i < len(mainArray)):
        if(containsAll(containsAllOfThese=valueCorrespondsTo, containingArray = mainArray[i])):
            if(printMessages == True):
                print("The elements of the array:\n", valueCorrespondsTo)
                print("Are contained in the array:\n", str(mainArray[i])+"\n")
            j = 0
            while(j < len(mainArray[i])):
                if(mainArray[i][j][0] == valueToRetrieve):

                    print(mainArray[i][j])

                    correspondingValues += [mainArray[i][j][1]]
                j += 1
        i += 1
    print("The retrieved values for", valueToRetrieve, "from", valueCorrespondsTo, "are", correspondingValues)
    return correspondingValues
```

Here are a couple examples of this function in use:

```
'''
This function call returns the Python function that corresponds to System.out.println in Java.
'''
print(getCorrespondingValue("Python", [["Java", "System.out.println"]]))

'''
This function call returns the Java function that corresponds to console.log in JavaScript.
'''
print(getCorrespondingValue("Java", [["JavaScript", "console.log"]]))
```

Comment: What's wrong with my solution here? Why did it get downvoted? (I'm guessing that it's because my solution is more complicated than it needs to be).

Comment: I didnt downvote but it may be because your question/answer seems to boil down to "how do I store pairs of strings", not that thats not a fair question to ask but why dress it up

Comment: Actually, I don't get why someone would upvote this at all. Your question in itself is rather trivial and shows a shallow understanding of data structures; your answer is probably the worst piece of working python code I've seen all week. There's not a single line I don't have a problem with (well, the return statements are ok). Your knowledge of python seems to come from knowing other languages and skimming over python syntax, it feels like you're writing php code in python. Thus I can't _not_ downvote this to make sure people exposed to it don't mistake it for a good solution...